# how do I determine the position of a LI in a jquery sortable list?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

After I move (sort) one of my list items I would like to know which position it just got dropped into.  I'm pretty sure this is impossible to calculate off of ui.position/offset since I have been able to drop onto the same pixel and have the item go in two different slots, depending on which direction I dragged the element from.

I suppose I can do some traversing and counting after the object is dropped but I was hoping that there was some direct way of getting this piece of info.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets what I need.

ui.item.prevAll().length + 1

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article for [smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/22/progressive-enhancement-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it/) that gets the order of li's for sending through to a backend. You might find the drag and drop/jquery parts of the tutorial useful.